# How to make only few datatype which is not related to each other acceptable by generics

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, coproduct

There is a trait which works perfectly. However, I would like to refactor the part related to generic [T] in order to limit the data type which could be accepted by generic [T] (I need only Option[JsValue] , JsValue , StringEnumEntry , String ). Is it possible to solve this problem through shapeless coproduct? Maybe there are other solutions?

```
trait ParameterBinders extends Log {

  def jsonBinder[T](json: T, jsonType: java.lang.String = "json"): ParameterBinderWithValue = {
    val jsonObject = new PGobject()
    jsonObject.setType(jsonType)
    json match {
      case json: Option[JsValue] =>
        jsonObject.setValue(json.map(Json.stringify).orNull)
      case json: JsValue =>
        jsonObject.setValue(Json.stringify(json))
      case json: StringEnumEntry =>
        jsonObject.setValue(json.value)
      case json: String =>
        jsonObject.setValue(json)
      case _ =>
        logger.error("unexpected data type ")
    }
    if (jsonType == "JSONSCHEMATYPE" || jsonType == "SYSPROPERTYTYPE") {
      ParameterBinder(this, (ps, i) => {
        ps.setObject(i, jsonObject)
      })
    } else {
      ParameterBinder(json, (ps, i) => {
        ps.setObject(i, jsonObject)
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I came across this issue before, may be this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495047/scala-variable-with-multiple-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an ADT as described in the link of the first comment.
If you don't want to change the types that are accepted in `jsonBinder` then you can solve the problem by using a typeclass.

e.g.

```
trait JsonBindValue[T] {
    def value(t: T): String
}
```

you would then have to provide instances for your accepted datatypes

```
object JsonBindValue {
    implicit val OptJsBinder = new JsonBindValue[Option[JsValue]] {
        def value(t: Option[JsValue]): String = {
            t.map(Json.stringify).orNull
        }
    }
   ... more instances here
}
```

finally your function would look like this:

```
def jsonBinder[T : JsonBindValue](json: T, jsonType: java.lang.String = "json"): ParameterBinderWithValue = {
    val binder = implicitly[JsonBindValue[T]]
    jsonObject.setType(jsonType)
    jsonObject.setValue(binder.value(json))
    ...
}
```

if you call the function without a implicit instance in scope you will get a compile time error.

Comment: Nice answer. Its just that these types do not qualify as ADT's. So it will be great, if we just replace ADT by `type class` and remove that piece of mis-information.