# Does Scala support an OR composition?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, composition, union-types

That question may be a dumb one where any search engine should give me a quick answer. However I did not find anything, so I may use the wrong terms.

If *F#* one can do an exclusive (OR) composition with the `|` symbol :

```
type LeftOrRightOrNone = 
   | Left of string
   | Right of string
   | None
```

Which mean that a `LeftOrRightOrNone` can only be of type `Left` OR `Right` OR `None`.

We can have the same constraint with a *sealed trait*:

```
sealed trait LeftOrRightOrNone
case class Left(..) extends LeftOrRightOrNone
case class Right(..) extends LeftOrRightOrNone
case object None extends LeftOrRightOrNone
```

But I wonder if there is a simpler way to declare such types in Scala ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can try Scala 3 http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala variable with multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495047/scala-variable-with-multiple-types)

Comment: @TomerShetah no, not really. That answer is the same as my proposal with _sealed trait_. My question was to have a simpler way to declare them.

Comment: Scala 2 doesn't natively support coproduct. Use shapeless library or wait for Scala 3

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "OR composition"? From my admittedly limited knowledge of F#, what you show has nothing to do with "OR" or "composition", but is simply a Closed Algebraic Sum Type.

Comment: It would *really* help if you could define precisely what you are looking for. So far, one answerer has interpreted your question as being about *sum types* while another answerer has interpreted your question as being about *union types* which are two very different things. It is totally unclear what you mean by "OR composition". I could not find that term in the F# Language Specification or any documentation associated with F#, nor in the Scala Language Specification or documentation, and Google doesn't seem to know it either.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2 you need to write it with sealed traits and case classes like you described. Scala 3 has much nicer syntax for this:

```scala
enum Either[+A, +B]:
   case Left(a: A)
   case Right (b: B)
```

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Scala. You have to approximate it via sealed traits as shown.

However, there is a way to [encode union types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312508/402428) leveraging the Curry-Howard Isomorphism.